# Unable to remove setInterval() function after condition match

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have setup some functionality in which api is hitting inside `setInterval()` functipon until condition matches but  after condition matched I want to stop `setInterval()` function.Below is my code:

```
  const myApi:any = () => {
        this.logger.log('Wait for 5 second...')
       
        const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/unknown';
        const me = axios.get(url).then((response) => {
             this.logger.log(response.data.total);
        }).catch((error) => {
           this.logger.log(error);
        });
        return me;
    }
    const myInterval = setInterval(myApi, 5000);
    if(myApi === 12){
        this.logger.log('Stopped');
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }
```

When result is coming 12 its not stopping as I am using `clearInterval()` function someone let me know how do I resolve this.

Comment: `myApi` is a function. It will never be equal to `12` ? Even if you do `myApi()`, it returns a Promise from `axios`, which will never be `12` either.

Comment: you have to place your condition into myApi function

Comment: But its returning  the value 12 and thats I am  trying to compare

Comment: Do you mean you are relying on `response.data.total` to be `12` ?

Comment: @Psidom yes exactly

Comment: @MahamudulHasan on putting clearInterval() finction inside myApi() it is working and matching the condition as well